# How to control which links are automatically turned into links

Tags: email, url, links

I'm working on a site that has a template which shows a range of information.

Firstly the page shows a few paragraphs of text. These often contain email addresses within the text, meaning I'd like to have 'Automatically turn URL's into links' turned on.

Secondly, the page shows some contact information, including an email address, which I'd like to display as 'Email Address: Click here' rather than 'Email Address: Someone@abc.com' due to space restrictions. In this case, if I turn on 'Automatically turn URL's into links' I get a lot of strange code output on the front-end.

I'm trying to avoid splitting this information between two different channels, as it makes sense for the customer to be able to enter or edit both peices of content from the same screen.

Does anyone know a way to enable automatic links for the channel but stop the issue with the 'Email Address: Click here'?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the email address tag with the [**No Formatting**](https://github.com/EllisLab/No-Formatting) plugin tags.

```
{exp:no_formatting}
    {email}
{/exp:no_formatting}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly that doesn't work. The following code is still being output: Email: /*','a','/','<',' 107',' 117',' 46',' 103',' 114',' 111',' 46',' 101',' 114',' 97',' 99',' 110',' 111',' 100',' 110',' 101',' 114',' 98',' 64',' 111',' 102',' 110',' 105',' 110',' 111',' 116'... ...','t','l','i','a','m','\"','=','f','e','r','h','a ','<'],i = l.length,j = el.length;while (--i >= 0)out += unescape(l[i].replace(/^\s\s*/, '&#'));while (--j >= 0)if (el[j].getAttribute('data-eeEncEmail_LlRbgeEKCd'))el[j].innerHTML = out;/*]]>*/">Click here