# Is there a way to disable auto-convert URLs and email addresses into links for custom member fields?

Tags: templates, members, settings

I have created a custom member field, `{Google_Plus_URL}`, where a URL like, *https://plus.google.com/1051794532082275037724* can be entered.

In my template, I reference this field as such:

```
{if Google_Plus_URL}
<p>Connect with <a rel="author" href="{Google_Plus_URL}">{screen_name} on Google+</a></p>
{/if}
```

The end result is, unexpectedly:

```
<p>Connect with <a rel="author" href="<a href="https://plus.google.com/1051794532082275037724">https://plus.google.com/1051794532082275037724</a>">Mike Adamick on Google+</a></p>
```

In researching this issue, I come across the "Automatically turn URLs and email addresses into links" options in relation to channels, but there doesn't appear to be an similar setting for member data. Aside from using a plugin like the one proposed in [this similar question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/17078/how-to-control-which-links-are-automatically-turned-into-links), is there a built in solution I'm missing?

I'm using EE v2.5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is still not possible. Not a great answer, but unfortunately it's hardcoded into the member functionality.

Comment: I tried the plugin referenced in my question, but it doesn't work the way I thought it would. Instead, I created my own simple plugin that pulls the raw data directly from the database. I call it, [Raw Member Field](https://github.com/Azannah/ee-raw-member-field).